# Which event handler to call to select element like Google dictionary Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome browser extension that has to display popup when a user selects a piece of text just like this Google Chrome dictionary plugin.I've been searching a lot but couldn't find any method. I want to make a popup like this and the text selected should also appear in the popup , I've tried a onselect() in JS but couldn't get what is needed.

[image]

Can anyone explain in the form of a pseudo code or algorithm? Exact code isn't required; examples are welcome.

My code which is faulty and is based purely on "click" event listener is not working , I need a better event handler which only triggers when the text is selected.

```
  document.body.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var selObj = window.getSelection();
  var selectedText = selObj.toString();
  alert(selectedText);

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The select event is only available for input elements and textarea elements.
So you could either use one of those in your html and use some css to make it look like a normal element.

Or you could create some function that triggers on mousedown and mouseup and then looks at the Selection API to check if your user selected some text.
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Selection