# No alert box while using window.selection() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an alert when a user selects some text on a web page.
The alert should have the same text as selected by the user.Whenever a user selects some text **only then** the alert should pop out.

Two different approaches that I've tried.

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
alert(selectionContents);
```

Output:
**No Alert BOX**

```
var selObj = window.getSelection();
var selectedText = selObj.toString();
alert(selectedText);
```

Output: **Empty alert box.**

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Selection

Comment: Check the console, maybe something is null;

Comment: The problem you're running into is that there's no event that fires when text is selected, so it can't go on to launching an alert

Comment: What event should I make ? I've checked [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) can you please provide a brief snippet I've been stuck for two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your logic in an event handler, the `click` event should work, because selecting usually involves clicking on an element. You might also want to bind your handler to the `keyup` event in case the user is selecting text using keyboard.

I used the page `body` but you could use whatever else container you prefer for your text.

Html:

```
<body>Some text to select. Only alert when "Some text" is highlighted.<body>
```

Javascript:

```
// add event listener to table
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    var selectedText = selObj.toString();
    if (selectedText === "Some text") {
        alert(selectedText);
    }
}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jj8yoa8L/1/

Comment: Problem with this solution is that whenever the user clicks on webpage regardless, there will be an empty alert thrown. The correct solution should alert only when the user selects the text and not revolve around clicking event handler . There has to be an alternative for that.

Comment: Okay thanks for downvoting , your answer has been marked correct

Comment: I am only alerting if selectedText is equal to some value, so there is no way of having an empty alert with my code. You must have copied it introducing some mistake. You are welcome on the down vote, check your code before asking for solutions.

Comment: Just tell me the event handler that is to be used I can figure out the rest.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066569/which-event-handler-to-call-to-select-element-like-google-dictionary-chrome-exte)

Comment: I have nothing to add to this answer, I already answered to the best of my knowledge.